# g++ compilation using 'include' statement with non-relative paths (C++)

Tags: c++, path, include, g++, libraries

I am trying to compile a c++ code with a third party library using g++ as a compiler.
My main.cpp needs to include the header file core.hpp while the core.hpp needs to include cvdef.h whereas cvdef.h need to include interface.h.

The paths for these three headers in the include statements are as follows:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/cvdef.h"
#include "opencv2/core/hal/interface.h"
```

See file structure in image below.

When I compile my main.cpp it finds the core.hpp. The core.hpp, however, cannot seems to find cvdef.h as it is looking within the 'core'-folder for the 'opencv2'-folder (which is a level below).
Without changing the paths in the include statement, how would I go about this?

My current compile statement using g++ under Windows is:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that OpenCV2 wants to look for the header files in standard locations.

You can add to the list of standard locations by using the `-I` (upper-case i) option, specifying the path to add.

In your case you should be able to do it with

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -Iopencv2/core
```

Comment: I cannot get it to work. I am still getting the same error: opencv2/core.hpp:52:32: fatal error: opencv2/core/cvdef.h: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/core/cvdef.h"

Comment: @Christian If you showed the error message in your question, I would have put the correct path directly in my answer. For future questions please *always* include the error messages you get, in full and complete.

Comment: @Christian As for your problem, the path you need to add seems to be `.`. So the option should be `-I.`.